# I need help, i'm either blind or stupid. PHP Search form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I haven't done this type of work in a long time, i'm sort of rusty still and really tired.

So here goes nothing, I have 2 search.php one for client side and one for server side. Im also using link.php to handle the mysql request. If there could be a kind soul to look over this mess would be great.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\dummy\htdocs\connection\search.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: upc in C:\dummy\htdocs\connection\search.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\dummy\htdocs\connection\search.php on line 28
```

**Mysql connection(connection/link.php)**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

 $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

**client side search.php(public_Html/search.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php include 'connection/link.php'; ?>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Inventory</title>
    <style>
    .redrum {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);top:50%;left: 61%;position: absolute;right: 0;bottom: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1><img src="" width="80px">8Ballshop Products</h1>
<div class="container">
    <form style="height:40px" action="" method="GET">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="ID or Link" name="search">&nbsp;
    </form>
<?php include 'connection/search.php'; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server Side search.php(connection/search.php)**

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT products.id, products.upc FROM inventory.products";
if( isset($_GET['search']) ){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']));
    $sql = "SELECT products.id as id, products.upc FROM inventory.products WHERE products.id = '$id';
    UNION
    SELECT products.id as id, products.upc WHERE products.upc = '$upc'";
}
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
?>
    <table class="table table-striped"> 
<tr>
<th>Product ID</th>
<th>Product Link</th>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['upc']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
<?php echo $row['products.upc']; ?>
<?php mysqli_close($link); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) the string is not safe!

Comment: What specifically are you having issues with? Are you getting any errors? You might get better answers from codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @computercarguy Thanks for you reply, here are my errors `
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\dummy\htdocs\connection\search.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: upc in C:\dummy\htdocs\connection\search.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\dummy\htdocs\connection\search.php on line 28`

@JasonK Yes i am aware escaping strings can be dangerous but for this project it is not a problem and only site admins can access this page :D

Comment: @REDRUM, you should edit your answer and include that, rather than leaving in Comments.

Comment: @computercarguy Sorry about that, I have updated the post!

Comment: The code that performs the search needs to check if the form was submitted with `if(isset($_GET['name']))`

Comment: Otherwise it will try to perform a search when the user simply loads the page.

Comment: @Barmar Oh right, I did that now the errors are gone but it doesnt give me any data back.. :/

Comment: The title for your question needs to be modified. It won't help in searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your errors, you haven't declared `$id` or `$upc` anywhere.

- You declare `$name`, but you don't use is, so maybe that was supposed to be `$id`?
- You use `products.upc` later on, so is that supposed to be `$upc`?

A `while` loop is supposed to have a comparison in the parenthesis, not an assignment. Are you wanting a `foreach` instead? If you do, you should assign your `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to an array variable first.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Becomes:

```
$resultsArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach ($resultsArray as $row) {
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Also, just because admins are the only uses of these pages, it doesn't mean they won't accidentally do something stupid, or someone who shouldn't have access will. It's always a good bit of practice to do basic security, such as SQL injection prevention, at all times.

Comment: That is true, I learned to combine mysql with php using select queries this way. I didnt know there was a better way of doing it until today. I will keep this post as reference for the future. 

I am only using this to log product links and assign them an numerical id, wouldnt there by a way to prevent sql injections by rejecting certain characters such as "(; ? I already wrote some js to stop 0's for being inputed, surely that would stop SQLi mistakes.

Also the issue was the = $upc and = $id  that were in the union query. It had to be set to $name :D

You guys are awesome.

Comment: @REDRUM, the PHP SQL injection would be another question, but it's already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php.